# Some inputs are being missed in pygame.event.get()

Tags: python, pygame

**NVM FIXED**: It was my computer palm rejection that prevented a left click from being registered when I was clicking other keyboard keys. So check that!

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I am calling pygame.event.get() in my core game loop once per frame, and it seems to be get my WASD inputs just fine with almost zero delay, but left mouse click inputs are often missed. It almost seems like all other inputs except WASD feel very delayed?

Here is the relevant code:

```py
 def processInput(self):
        events = pygame.event.get()

        if len(events) != 0:
            print(events)

        for event in events:
            match event.type:
                case pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False
                    break
                case pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    self.inputs.append(event.key)
                case pygame.KEYUP:
                    self.inputs.remove(event.key)
                case pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    print("button down!")
                    b = event.button
                    a = -1

                    match(b):
                        case 1:
                            a = pygame.BUTTON_LEFT
                        case 2:
                            a = pygame.BUTTON_MIDDLE
                        case 3:
                            a = pygame.BUTTON_RIGHT
                        case _:
                            pass

                    self.inputs.append(a)
                case pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    b = event.button
                    r = -1

                    match(b):
                        case 1:
                            r = pygame.BUTTON_LEFT
                        case 2:
                            r = pygame.BUTTON_MIDDLE
                        case 3:
                            r = pygame.BUTTON_RIGHT
                        case _:
                            pass

                    self.inputs.remove(r)
                case _:
                    pass
```

The print statement in the fourth case is not being printed, so I know it's not with my input processing later down the loop. Any help or insight would be appreciated!

I've tried rebinding the action to another keyboard key instead of left click and it feels delayed too. Only the WASD keys seem to be working with no problems. So it does not seem like an issue with MOUSEBUTTONDOWN specifically with pygame, but then I have no idea what it is then.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I would use normal `if/elif/else` to make code more readable.

Comment: BTW: variable `pygame.BUTTON_LEFT` has value `1` - so you get `event.button` with value `1` and you use `match/case` to assing `a = pygame.BUTTON_LEFT` which gives `a = 1` - it is waste of time, You get the same result  with single line `a = event.button`

Answer (score 0):

It was my computer palm rejection that prevented a left click from being registered when I was clicking other keyboard keys. So check that!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).